# Different output release compared to debug

Tags: c#, debugging, output, genetic-algorithm

I have a question concerning output about my genetic algorithm I'm creating. I seem to get different output when I just run my project compared to when I debug at a specific location.

Part of my code looks as follows:

```
Population mutatePopulation(Population pop)
    {
        foreach(Chromosome x in pop.population)
        {
            x.mutateChromosome(x);
        }
        return pop;
    }
```

In the code above, I want some of my Chromosome objects to mutate. This is done by the following method:

```
public Chromosome mutateChromosome(Chromosome x)
    {
        Chromosome result = x;
        //SWAP mutation
        Random rnd = new Random();
        double value = rnd.NextDouble();
        if (value < MUTATION_RATE)
        {
            int index1 = (int)rnd.Next(0, x.customerSequence.Count() - 1);
            int index2 = (int)rnd.Next(0, x.customerSequence.Count() - 1);
            Console.WriteLine(  "Muation at chromosome: " + x.ToString() + ", mutation at indexes [" + index1 + "," + index2+ 
                                "], values ["+x.customerSequence[index1].index+","+x.customerSequence[index2].index+"]");
            Customer cust1 = x.customerSequence[index1];
            Customer cust2 = x.customerSequence[index2];
            result.customerSequence[index1] = cust2;
            result.customerSequence[index2] = cust1;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

When I run my project I (sometimes, depends on random variable) get the following output:

```
Generation #14 
10 12 9 5 4 2 8 13 6 3 7 11  ||  Fitness: 3209
11 6 12 3 5 9 10 4 7 2 8 13  ||  Fitness: 3252
13 8 11 4 10 3 6 5 9 2 12 7  ||  Fitness: 3301
10 9 4 11 6 13 12 3 5 8 2 7  ||  Fitness: 3315
7 3 9 10 11 4 13 8 6 2 5 12  ||  Fitness: 3354
6 10 4 8 13 2 7 12 3 5 11 9  ||  Fitness: 3361
10 7 13 5 8 9 3 6 11 4 2 12  ||  Fitness: 3394
11 12 5 8 10 4 9 13 2 7 3 6  ||  Fitness: 3499
11 13 12 9 3 4 7 5 10 6 2 8  ||  Fitness: 3708
8 9 6 5 2 13 11 7 10 3 4 12  ||  Fitness: 3819

Generation #15
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [5,7], values [2,13]
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [5,7], values [9,4]
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [5,7], values [3,5]
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [5,7], values [13,3]
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [5,7], values [4,8]
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [5,7], values [2,12]
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [5,7], values [9,6]
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [5,7], values [4,13]
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [5,7], values [4,5]
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [1,6], values [9,11]
13 8 11 4 10 5 6 3 9 2 12 7  ||  Fitness: 3025
11 6 12 3 5 4 10 9 7 2 8 13  ||  Fitness: 3088
10 7 13 5 8 6 3 9 11 4 2 12  ||  Fitness: 3112
10 12 9 5 4 13 8 2 6 3 7 11  ||  Fitness: 3315
6 10 4 8 13 12 7 2 3 5 11 9  ||  Fitness: 3381
11 13 12 9 3 5 7 4 10 6 2 8  ||  Fitness: 3689
10 9 4 11 6 3 12 13 5 8 2 7  ||  Fitness: 3730
7 3 9 10 11 8 13 4 6 2 5 12  ||  Fitness: 3733
11 12 5 8 10 13 9 4 2 7 3 6  ||  Fitness: 3755
8 11 6 5 2 13 9 7 10 3 4 12  ||  Fitness: 3808
```

It seems that when one Chromosome gets mutated, all the other do aswell.

However, when I debug I get the output I need:

```
Generation #2
2 13 3 12 7 5 4 10 11 9 8 6  ||  Fitness: 2823
13 6 11 5 2 9 4 10 7 8 12 3  ||  Fitness: 3019
4 13 12 8 6 10 7 3 5 11 9 2  ||  Fitness: 3254
3 7 11 4 2 8 9 10 13 5 6 12  ||  Fitness: 3267
3 4 2 8 9 5 11 7 6 10 13 12  ||  Fitness: 3309
2 7 5 8 9 4 10 3 6 12 13 11  ||  Fitness: 3448
12 4 2 5 8 10 6 13 11 3 9 7  ||  Fitness: 3484
7 12 8 11 5 3 10 13 2 9 6 4  ||  Fitness: 3712
11 7 5 6 4 3 12 13 2 9 8 10  ||  Fitness: 3775
2 6 12 10 11 13 3 4 8 9 7 5  ||  Fitness: 3846

Generation #3
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [1,3], values [6,5]
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [8,7], values [13,10]
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [8,8], values [6,6]
Muation at chromosome: XML.Chromosome, mutation at indexes [4,6], values [9,10]
2 13 3 12 7 5 4 10 11 9 8 6  ||  Fitness: 2823
3 7 11 4 2 8 9 13 10 5 6 12  ||  Fitness: 3249
4 13 12 8 6 10 7 3 5 11 9 2  ||  Fitness: 3254
3 4 2 8 9 5 11 7 6 10 13 12  ||  Fitness: 3309
13 5 11 6 2 9 4 10 7 8 12 3  ||  Fitness: 3434
2 7 5 8 10 4 9 3 6 12 13 11  ||  Fitness: 3443
12 4 2 5 8 10 6 13 11 3 9 7  ||  Fitness: 3484
7 12 8 11 5 3 10 13 2 9 6 4  ||  Fitness: 3712
11 7 5 6 4 3 12 13 2 9 8 10  ||  Fitness: 3775
2 6 12 10 11 13 3 4 8 9 7 5  ||  Fitness: 3846
```

Could someone help me with my problem? I have hunch it has something to do with the Random object I am using, but I can't seem to figure it out.
Thanks!

(PS. This is the first time I ask a question of my own here, so sorry if I'm not in compliance with the rules)

Comment: Why you need a double value for the array index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're creating a `new Random()` in your mutate method.  Don't do this.  If you mutate enough chromosomes quickly enough, each `Random` instance will get seeded with the same value and produce the same sequence of random numbers.

Instead, create a single instance of `Random` and use it for all chromosomes.  For example:

```
Population mutatePopulation(Population pop, Random random)
{
    foreach(Chromosome x in pop.population)
    {
        x.mutateChromosome(x, random);
    }
    return pop;
}

public Chromosome mutateChromosome(Chromosome x, Random rnd)
{
    Chromosome result = x;
    //SWAP mutation
    double value = rnd.NextDouble();
    if (value < MUTATION_RATE)
    {
        int index1 = (int)rnd.Next(0, x.customerSequence.Count() - 1);
        int index2 = (int)rnd.Next(0, x.customerSequence.Count() - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(  "Muation at chromosome: " + x.ToString() + ", mutation at indexes [" + index1 + "," + index2+ 
                            "], values ["+x.customerSequence[index1].index+","+x.customerSequence[index2].index+"]");
        Customer cust1 = x.customerSequence[index1];
        Customer cust2 = x.customerSequence[index2];
        result.customerSequence[index1] = cust2;
        result.customerSequence[index2] = cust1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

At some point this single random instance will be created and stored in a field.  I can't say where the best place for that would be without understanding the architecture you've created, so I've moved the random instance to be a parameter to be passed to methods that need randomness.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I did not know that the Random instance worked that way. This solved my problem indeed :-)

Comment: @Marijn, if this resolved your problem, consider marking the answer.